# Making Button span across VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have the following SwiftUI view:

```
HStack {
  ...
  VStack {
    TextField { ... }
    SecureField { ... }
    Button { ... }
  }
  ...
}
```

[image]

I've added a `.background(Color.green)` to the `Button`, and as you can see, the view is very snug to the text.

I'm wondering if there's a way to adjust the width of the button so that it fills across `VStack` - something like a `.fill` mode for `UIStackView`.

Comment: Adding .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) to button can do same. But it will always be center aligned.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The best way to do this is setting `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on the content of the button.

```
Button(action: handleSignInAction) {
    Text("Sign In")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.background(Color.green)
```

---

Old answer from 2019:

You could use a `HStack` with a `Text` and `Spacer` to get a `Button` that fills the width of its parent:

```
Button(action: handleSignInAction) {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Sign In")
        Spacer()
    }
}.background(Color.green)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it forces the next to be left justified.

Comment: You could also add a `Spacer()` before the `Text("Sign In")`, that should make the text centred.

Comment: The updated answer doesn't work. The `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` makes the button *look* wider, but the tappable area isn't any wider.

Answer (score 14):

@d.felber's answer is almost complete, but you'd need a `Spacer()` on each side to center:

```
Button(action: {
    // TODO: ...
}) {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Sign In")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` **inside** the `Button` like this:

```swift
Button(action: {...}) {
    Text("Sign In")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.tint(.green)
```

Not like this, because the tappable area doesn't stretch:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Sign In")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(Color.green)
```

Comment: This is the only suggestion that worked for me when the Button label is an Image. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The button *looks* like it's the proper width, but the tappable area isn't any bigger.

Comment: @DanielT. It should be applied to the content of the button.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to stick to the method SwiftUI docs suggest you need to use GeometryReader and set the buttons width manually. Geometry reader updates its properties for different devices and upon rotation.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
     Button().frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach - though just wrapping in geometry reader seems to work with no further changes required.   It does fail for multiline text though, as the text goes to full parent height instead of just the height required.

Comment: Upon further testing, it's best to set width as above, but to not specify height.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me on macOS Big Sur. If the others don't work, try this.

Answer (score 4):

Make the button text's frame the size of the `UIScreen` and then set the background color after it (make sure all style changes are done *after* changing the frame size, otherwise the style changes will only be visible on the original default frame). The frame size will propagate upward to increase the width of the button to the width of the screen as well.:

```
Button(action: {
                // Sign in stuff
            }) {
                Text("Sign In")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.green)
            }
```

You can also add some negative horizontal padding in between setting the frame and background in order to offset from the edge of the screen:

```
Button(action: {
                    // Sign in stuff
                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.horizontal, -10.0)
                    .background(Color.green)
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Button(action: {
    // Do your login thing here
}) {
    Capsule()
        .frame(height: 44)
        .overlay(Text("Login").foregroundColor(Color.white)).padding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a `.fill` method similar to `UIStackView` but, if what you want to do is provide some spacing on the `Button` (or any view for that matter) what worked for me is either setting the `frame` or `padding`

`.frame(width: 300, alignment: .center)` (we can also set a height here but, if not it should be able to infer the height based on the button text.

If you don't want to set an arbitrary width, you can also `import UIKit` and make use of `UIScreen` and get the devices full width. (There may be a SwiftUI way of getting this but, haven't found it at this time yet)

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .center)
```

and then you can add a little bit of padding for some breathing room

`.padding(.all, 20)`

The issue with the padding is that it will add onto the additional width of the screen so we would have to take into account when setting the width.

(20 * 2 sides from leading and trailing)

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, alignment: .center)
```

(breathing room is for when the text covers to the end of the screen or if your alignment is `.leading` or `.trailing`)