# How to make a rectangle's height the same height of a VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that consists of an HStack with a rectangle and a VStack of text inside. I want to make the height of the rectangle the same as the height of the VStack. I have already tried looking through many other questions here on StackOverflow but I didn't find an answer. Can anyone help me do that?

Here is my code:

```swift
struct TodoView: View {
    @State var todos = ["feed the dog", "take the dog out for a walk", "make coffee"]
    @State var height: CGFloat = 45
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                .frame(width: 1)
                .foregroundColor(Color("lightGray"))
                .padding()
            VStack{
                
                Text("Todo")
                    .font(.title)
                ForEach(todos, id: \.self){ todo in
                    Text(todo)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the GeometryReader and PreferenceKey to make this possible.

```
struct SiblingHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize? {
        nil
    }

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize?, nextValue: () -> CGSize?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}

struct TodoView: View {
    @State var vStackSize: CGSize? = nil
    @State var todos = ["feed the dog", "take the dog out for a walk", "make coffee"]
    @State var height: CGFloat = 45
    var body: some View {
                HStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: self.vStackSize?.width, height: self.vStackSize?.height)
                    VStack{

                        Text("Todo")
                            .font(.title)
                        ForEach(todos, id: \.self){ todo in
                            Text(todo)
                        }
                    }.background(
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Color.clear.preference(key: SiblingHeightKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                        }
                    )

                    Spacer()
                }.onPreferenceChange(SiblingHeightKey.self) {
                    self.vStackSize = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the SiblingHeightKey is referring to?

Comment: Updated in answer

Comment: I get an error that says "Thread 1: signal SIGBART" on the line "Color.clear.preference(key: SiblingHeightKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                        }"

Comment: Your error must be somewhere else, try just this code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late for this, but actually, there’s no need for `GeometryReader`, you can do this instead:

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
            .frame(width: 1)
            .foregroundColor(Color("lightGray"))
            .padding()
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

        VStack {
            Text("Todo")
                .font(.title)
            ForEach(todos, id: \.self) { todo in
                Text(todo)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

        Spacer()
    }
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
```

> The key is to give each view infinite maximum height or width, which
> will automatically make it stretch to fill all the available space.
> You then apply fixedSize() to the container they are in, which tells
> SwiftUI those views should only take up the space they need.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-two-views-the-same-width-or-height

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.frame` modifier:

```
HStack{
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
        .frame(width: 1, height: 50)
        .foregroundColor(Color("lightGray"))
        .padding()
    VStack {
        Text("Todo")
            .font(.title)
        ForEach(todos, id: \.self){ todo in
            Text(todo)
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

If you want to have them fill the whole `View`:

```
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Alternatively, you can use `GeometryReader` as proposed here: [Make a grid of buttons of same width and height in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658558/make-a-grid-of-buttons-of-same-width-and-height-in-swiftui).